# How to use avro files as input to a MRJob job?

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, mrjob

I need to take avro files as input to a mrjob hadoop job. I can't find any documentation on how to do that unless I pass extra commands to the hadoop streaming jar. This will complicate development though because I've been using the `inline` runner to test locally.

Is it possible to use the `inline` runner to read avro files with MRJob?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to tell Hadoop what is the format of your "Input Format" of your Hadoop job:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar 
  ;; other params go here
  -inputformat org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroAsTextInputFormat
```

But I'm not sure how you run MRJobs. My previous solution is working if you are using Plain Hadoop.

Comment: Thanks I found that yesterday. I guess I'll just have to install a local hadoop instance and develop against that instead unless there are any other answers...

Answer (score 0):

As Chiron explained you need to specify the Hadoop Input Format.
This can be done with by setting the `HADOOP_INPUT_FORMAT` option in MRJob

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.protocol import JSONProtocol
class MRAvro(MRJob):
    # Converts each AVRO record into one JSON record per line 
    HADOOP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroAsTextInputFormat'
    # Reads each JSON line into 
    INPUT_PROTOCOL = JSONProtocol

    def mapper(self, avro_record, _):
        # TODO

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        # TODO
```

In your configuration you need to make sure that the .jar file for `AvroAsTextInputFormat` is available on the cluster; as of v0.5.3 you can use `--libjar` at the command line, or configure libjars in the mrjob configuration file (at the time of v0.5.3 is not released; see the discussion on `--libjar` in the [feature request](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/issues/198)).

I am not aware of an easy way to integrate local testing with AVRO (`HADOOP_INPUT_FORMAT` is ignored by local runners). One solution is to convert your test data with the tojson method of Apache avro-tools.

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar test_data.avro > test_data.json
```

Otherwise you could write your own function in python using the avro or fastavro libraries to prepare the data for local execution.